# nagios levels of escalation

Tags: nagios

I try to configure nagios in the following way

for every service (for example "mysql seconds behind master") I need to define few levels of escalations, when **level is warning** I want to send only email and when **level is critical** I want to send email and sms .

What is the right way to do this?

Do be stick we the levels definition (critical or warning), if there is different way to differentiate email level and sms level of escalation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For every kind of notification you get to define `service_notification_commands` or `host_notification_commands`. So, to do this or that depending on the condition is up to the command you define. Write your own script, pass it the `SERVICESTATE` or `HOSTSTATE` macros. Send as many emails or SMSes as you want depending on the state.